# Ajax popup not showing after product add if friendly url is active in Pretsashop 1.7.1

Tags: jquery, ajax, nginx, prestashop-1.7

When I am adding a product to the cart, ajax popup & shopping cart works fine if friendly url is not activated.

However when I add a product to shopping cart with friendly url turned on then the ajax popup and shopping cart icon doesnt show up. Here is the part of nginx server config.

Any suggestion/comments most welcome. Thanks!

```
    rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg l$
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$
    rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(-[.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2$3.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/images_ie/?([^/]+).(jpe?g|png|gif)$ /js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 last;
    rewrite ^/order$ /index.php?controller=order last;

    # Symfony controllers
    location ~ /(international|_profiler|module|product|combination|specific-price)/(.*)$ {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args $admin_dir/index.php$is_args$args;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can typically happen if in the SEO & URLs page you use the same simplified URL for both **cart** and **module-ps_shoppingcart-ajax** pages.

Additionally if you have more than one language configured make sure that each language has a different URL for both of those pages.

Answer (score 1):

In 1.7.4.1 the problem was me was in this part:

```
$admin_dir/index.php$is_args$args;
```

So it happened to redirect /module/ps_shoppingcart/ajax to admin.

I then have found [this](https://gist.github.com/vicobits/86804fa5f6bd9e2a38f353518563590f) nginx config to be working for me.
It adds in particular

```
    rewrite "^/module/([_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/([_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)$" /index.php?fc=module&module=$1&controller=$2 last;
```

Which comes before any location directives which avoids this conflict.
Note, I use Symfony rewrites from my previous config:

```
location ~ /(international|_profiler|module|product|feature|attribute|supplier|combination|specific-price|configure|addons)/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args $admin_dir/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Where configure and addons are required for admin some admin sections.